# I don't want to send an Empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, each

I am sending data to the server with TextBox. But I specifically want to send textboxes with value. If no value is entered, the textbox will not be sent.
How would I be able to send textboxes with a value?

```
  $.ajax({type: "GET",
    url:myurl,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obje = jQuery.parseJSON(msg)
        var i = 0;
        $('#wrapper *').filter(':input').each(function () {
             $(this).attr('id', i);
            if (i)
                field += " and ";
            field = field  + "[" + obje[i].Name+ "]" + "=" + "'" + $(this).val() + "'";
            i++;

        });
```

Comment: So where/what is your problem?

Comment: Just test your input value before send `ajax`, if the value isn't empty ajax is send elle you can display `alert` for example

Comment: You want to send data to the server and yet your request is GET. Can you specify your exact issue?

Comment: @Simple_Programmer I just want to know . İf no value is entered, the textbox is'not sent. :)

Comment: @simon Sorry dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 var txtvalue=$(this).val();
  if(txtvalue !=""){
    if (i)
     {

            field += " and ";
        field = field  + "[" + obje[i].Name+ "]" + "=" + "'" + $(this).val() + "'";
    }

 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use validations either client side or server side validation. In case Client side validation if form is not valid form is not post back. And in case of server side form is postback and then validation performed.

so if you do not allow to send data to server when the textbox is empty use client side validation.

Comment: Thank you but I just want to send it when a value is entered. So I do not have to enter the value

Comment: so you need to check textbox that have value or not?

Answer (score 0):

@Front end developer, if i am instead of you i will use validation (client or server side).that check Textbox value. if Textbox is Empty than no value submited to server, so first fill that textbox and submit. so my advice is to use Jquery validation or any other validation.
or another way is that check value of textbox before ajax call. like this..

```
 var txt = $('#txtName');  
                if (txt.val() == null && txt.val() == '') {  
                    alert('Please enter text')  
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var txt = $('#txtName');  
            if (txt.val() == null || txt.val() == '') {  
                alert('Please enter text')  
            }
```

this will work as val cannot be null as well as  '' at the same time.